# JavaScript functions do not work when jquery loads an external page

Tags: php, jquery

I have to make a div load an external file every minute. It does load the file but the JQuery functions don't work. Is there any other way I can load the file so that the JavaScript functions work?
My JQuery code-

```
emaild = $("#hidden").val();
           var refresh = setInterval(function() {
          $("#load").load('aposts.php?id='+emaild);
       }, 60000);
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Sorry for the bad English :P

Answer (score 0):

I see you defining `emaid` and referencing `emaild`

Comment: thats ok I changed it but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var $div = $('#myDiv');


    var timer = setInterval( function() {
        $div.html( $("#load").load('aposts.php?id='+emaild) ); 
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: yes I did....I've edited the info in the question....by the way my question is how do I make the JavaScript function work??